# it doesn't loop but just breaks even if i input Y

Tags: python, if-statement, try-catch, except, finally

```py
def interact():
    while True: 
        try:
            num = int(input("Please input an integer: "))
            if (num % 2) == 0:
                print ("{0} is even".format(num))
            else:
                print("{0} is odd".format(num))
            num_two = int(input('Do you want to play again n/Y:'))
            
        except:
             if num_two == "y":
                continue 
        finally:
            print("Goodbye")
            break
```

Comment: You have a break in your finally block. The finally block is always run, and it always breaks. If you don't want it to break every time, don't put a break in your finally block.

Answer (score 0):

```
def interact(): 
   while True:
       try:
          num = int(input("Please input an integer: ")) 
          if (num % 2) == 0: print ("{0} is even".format(num))
          else: print("{0} is odd".format(num))
          num_two = int(input('Do you want to play again n/Y:'))
       except:
          if num_two == "y":
             continue 
       finally:
          print("Goodbye")
          break
```

the problem with this code is that the 'break' makes it so that you are out of the while true loop (i think)

therefore i think removing the 'break' might solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You must add specific error to except and remove break from finally:

```
try:
    user_input = input()
    int(user_input)
except ValueError:
    print('not a number')
    if user_input = 'y':
        continue
    else:
        break
finally:
    print('Finally')
```

Comment: what should I do to make it continue if the user inputs y?

Comment: I change my example. You must have another var for input before convert to int

Comment: Do you resolve your problem?